# Как сделать ожидание сообщения от пользователя? TeleBot

Tags: python, telebot

Я хочу адаптировать текстовую игру под бота в телеграме. Вся суть в том, что после вывода правил, человек дожен вводить числа, а бот должен их считывать и записывать в переменную.
Код в принципе работает, но есть один минус - он за пару минут сожрёт всю ОЗУ. Пытался добавлять "sleeр", ни к чему хорошему не привело.

Вот весь код:

```
import random
import re
import telebot

bot_token = "*****************************"
bot = telebot.TeleBot(bot_token)

NUM_DIGITS = 3
MAX_GUESSES = 10
a = 0
guess = ''


@bot.message_handler(commands=['bagels'])
def main(message):
    global a, guess
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id,""""Бaйглз" Дедуктивная игра.
Я загадываю любое {}-значимое число. Попробуй угадать его. Всего у тебя 10 попыток.
Вот некоторые расшифровки:
Когда я говорю:      Это значит:
"Пико"               Одна правильная цифра, но не на своем месте.
"Ферми"              Одна правильная цифра и на своем месте.
"Бaйглз"             Ни единой правильной цифры
Например, если секретная цифра 248, а ваш ответ 843, то компьютер скажет Ферми Пико.""".format(NUM_DIGITS))

    secretNum = getSecretNum()
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'У вас есть {} попыток, что-бы угадать число.'.format(MAX_GUESSES))
    numGuesses = 1
    while numGuesses <= MAX_GUESSES:
        guess = ''
        while len(guess) != NUM_DIGITS or not guess.isdecimal():
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Попытка #{}: '.format(numGuesses))
            a = 0
            while a != 1: # В этом цикле вся проблема

                @bot.message_handler(commands=re.compile(r"^[0-9]").search(message.text)) 
                def text(message):
                    global a, guess
                    guess = message.text
                    if len(guess) == 3:
                        a = 1

        clues = getClues(guess, secretNum)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text=clues)
        numGuesses += 1
        if guess == secretNum:
            break
        if numGuesses > MAX_GUESSES:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                             'У вас закончились попытки. Вы проиграли.\nЗагаданное число - {}.'.format(secretNum))
            break

def getSecretNum():
    numbers = list('0123456789')
    random.shuffle(numbers)
    secretNum = ''
    for i in range(NUM_DIGITS):
        secretNum += str(numbers[i])
    return secretNum


def getClues(guess, secretNum):
    if guess == secretNum:
        return 'Вы угадали!'
    clues = []
    for i in range(len(guess)):
        if guess[i] == secretNum[i]:
            clues.append('Ферми')
        elif guess[i] in secretNum:
            clues.append('Пико')
    if len(clues) == 0:
        return 'Байглз'
    else:
        clues.sort()
        return ' '.join(clues)


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я переписал игру немного, вот как решил:

```
import random
import telebot
import logging

bot_token = "*****************************************"
bot = telebot.TeleBot(bot_token)
telebot.logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

NUM_DIGITS = 3
guess = dict()


def init_storage(user_id):
    guess[user_id] = dict(attempt=None, secretNum=None)


def set_data_storage(user_id, key, value):
    guess[user_id][key] = value


def get_data_storage(user_id):
    return guess[user_id]


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text.lower() in ["байглз", "bagels"])
def main(message):
    init_storage(message.chat.id)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, """"Бaйглз" Дедуктивная игра.
Я загадываю любое {}-значимое число. Попробуй угадать его. Всего у тебя 10 попыток.
Вот некоторые расшифровки:
Когда я говорю:      Это значит:
"Пико"                      Одна правильная цифра, но не на своем месте.
"Ферми"                   Одна правильная цифра и на своем месте.
"Бaйглз"                   Ни единой правильной цифры
Например, если секретная цифра 248, а ваш ответ 843, то компьютер скажет Ферми Пико.""".format(NUM_DIGITS))

    secretNum = getSecretNum()
    attempt = 10
    set_data_storage(message.chat.id, "attempt", attempt)
    set_data_storage(message.chat.id, "secretNum", secretNum)
    print(get_data_storage(message.chat.id))
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'У вас есть 10 попыток, что-бы угадать число.')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(message, clue)


def getSecretNum():
    numbers = list('0123456789')
    random.shuffle(numbers)
    secretNum = ''
    for i in range(NUM_DIGITS):
        secretNum += str(numbers[i])
    return secretNum


def clue(message):
    guess = message.text

    if not guess.isdigit():
        msg = bot.reply_to(message, 'Вы ввели НЕ цифровое значение. Пожалуйста, введите 3-ех значное число')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, clue)
        return

    attempt = get_data_storage(message.chat.id)["attempt"]
    secretNum = get_data_storage(message.chat.id)["secretNum"]

    if guess == secretNum:
        bot.reply_to(message, "Вы угадали!")
        init_storage(message.chat.id)
        return
    elif attempt > 1:
        attempt -= 1
        clues = []
        for i in range(3):
            if guess[i] == secretNum[i]:
                clues.append('Ферми')
            elif guess[i] in secretNum:
                clues.append('Пико')
            if len(clues) == 0:
                clues.append('Байглз')
        else:
            clues.sort()
            clues = " ".join(clues)
        set_data_storage(message.chat.id, "attempt", attempt)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'{clues}\nОсталось попыток: {attempt}')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, clue)
    else:
        bot.reply_to(message,
                     'У вас закончились попытки. Вы проиграли.\nЗагаданное число - {}.'.format(secretNum))


print("Бот запущен ")
bot.polling(non_stop=True)
```